# Setting up a multi-currency price filter with Algolia React Instant Hooks

Tags: reactjs, filter, algolia

I am using React Instant Search Hooks and refinement list to filter my hits and I would like to set up a price filter. I have an array of objects for my items with the prices in different currencies.

When I define my attributesForFaceting, I can only select price.value, price.contribution... but I can't select the object according to its position in the array like price[0].value.

```
price

[{ value: 20, contribution: 0, currencyName: "Euro", currencyType: "FIAT", currencySymbol: "EUR" }
{ value: 19.41, contribution: 0, currencyName: "US dollar", currencyType: "FIAT", currencySymbol: "USD" }
{ value: 17.6, contribution: 0, currencyName: "British Pound Sterling", currencyType: "FIAT", currencySymbol: "GBP" }
{ value: 0.0151, contribution: 0, currencyName: "Ethereum", currencyType: "CRYPTO", currencySymbol: "ETH" }
{ value: 24.0794, contribution: 0, currencyName: "Polygon", currencyType: "CRYPTO", currencySymbol: "MATIC" }]
```

Is there a way to get only the first object on the array?
Can you recommend a way to deploy a price filter based on the currency selected?

Many thanks,

Comment: Please confirm `attributesForFaceting` or `price` is an Array.  What `price.value` is available means `price` is an object.  You can filter an array by `const selected value = price.find(x => x.currencyName==='Whatever')?.value`

Comment: Coming to this late, but I don't think you can accomplish what you are trying to do with an array. You'll need a data structure that puts the currency type first. There are some suggestions for indexing complex pricing in the Algolia documentation. https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/solutions/ecommerce/b2b-catalog-management/tutorials/personalized-pricing/#using-nested-attributes-for-pricing-tiers

Comment: Thanks, I will send the data to Algolia in another way